# Group by day using the timestamp field

Tags: mysql

My table schema looks like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name               | varchar(50   | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| modified           | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| created            | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to get a count of the names and group by number of names modified by day at the moment I can only group by the full date including the timestamp eg:

```
SELECT name, count(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY modified
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: And your actual _problem_ is? “How do I extract the date portion from a timestamp value?” Well that should be easy enough to research.

Comment: Questions about making MySQL queries requires source data as `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and INSERT's (place it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ or on https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ) or as ascii formatted text data tables.. We also need the expected output as a ascii formatted text data table.. For now i vote close this question to be "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use MySQL `DATE()` function to extract the date from the timestamp:

```
SELECT name, count(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE(mytable.modified);
```

> The `DATE()` function extracts the date value from a date or datetime expression.

Answer (score 6):

Dependant upon what you mean by day, you have a few options;
[Here's your cheat sheet.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

`DAYNAME(date)` for the day of the week (Mon-Sun)

`DAYOFMONTH(date)` for the day of the month (1-31)

`DAYOFWEEK(date)` for the day of the week (1-7)

`DAYOFYEAR(date)` for the day of the year (1-365)

## Edit:

If you want to group by the entire date (as opposed to a particular day), ignoring the time you can use

`DATE_FORMAT(date, format)`

The full list of format specifiers can be found at the above link, but what you'll probably need is:

`Date_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')`

This will format the date as 'YYYY-MM-DD' and you can group by that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query or a version of it 
**SELECT DATE_FORMAT(modified,"%Y-%m-%d") as date_string, count(1) FROM mytable group by date_string;**